# Linux ptrace() read whole memory page

Tags: android, c++, c, linux, ptrace

Hello I try to dump the memory of a process in Android/Linux. Right now I read the memory maps to get a memory region's address space and then I read every single word like this:

```
ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, pid, NULL, NULL);
wait(NULL);

read each word in this memory region:
word = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKDATA, pid, (void *)address, NULL);

ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, pid, NULL, NULL);
ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, pid, NULL, NULL);
```

Isn't there a more efficient solution reading directly a whole memory page by specifying the start/end of a memory address space to read?

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to achieve? A complete dump of the process can be done by reading the "file" `/proc/pid/mem`

Comment: I want a dump of all writeable memory pages. I achieved now a dump of the heap using _open_, _lseek_ and _read_.
But when I try to access the other memory regions like stack I still get an I/O error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible ways to read memory more efficiently from another process.

If your kernel supports it (I have no idea about Android kernels) you can use `process_vm_readv`.

Another way is to open the `/proc/.../mem` file of the target process and read from it.  gdb uses this method, though I think only because `process_vm_readv` is "new" (in gdb's terms).

Comment: _process_vm_readv_ is not available in Android -> results in _error: undefined reference to 'process_vm_readv'_
But thanks for your advice I managed it now to read the heap from _/proc/pid/mem_ using open, lseek and read.